# How to select the record with max id and sum the values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below table in SQL Server:

```
category    consumption total   id
-----------------------------------
A           40          100     1
A           60          200     2
B           60          100     6
B           40          200     7
C           10           50     3
```

Expected output :

```
consumption total
------------------
100         400
```

Logic :

1. Pick only the categories - A, B
2. If multiple records are available in categories - A, B. Pick one record with MAX id
3. Sum the consumption and total and display the results

Category A, 2 records are available : Pick record with MAX id.
In this case, MAX id = 2. consumption = 60, total = 200

Category B, 2 records are available : Pick record with MAX id.
In this case, MAX id = 7. consumption = 40, total = 200

Output will be the sum of both consumption and total.

I was able to draft the below query for one category but how to get another category and sum:

```
  Select 
      s.consumption, s.total, s.rn
  From 
      (select
           consumption, total
           row_number() over (partition by category order by id desc) as rn
       from 
           [dbo].[Table_1]
       where 
           category = ‘A’) as s
where 
    s.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use row_number() window function to return the row with the max id for both categories and aggregate:

```
select sum(t.consumption), sum(t.total)
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by category order by id desc) as rn
  from [dbo].[Table_1]   
  where category in ('A', 'B')
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating it.

Try this

```
select s.consumption,s.total,s.category
from
table s 
where id in 
(select max(Id) as id from table group by category) 
and category in ('A','B')  -- Or any other conditions
```

The subquery returns

- 2
- 7
- 3

So, simply get the associated values with these id number

Comment: Sorry, fixed the query